# How do I ask "if there is an exception, then do this" java

Tags: java, exception

I wanted to ask that if an exception occurs, then display a certain String in the textfield. When I try using a try, catch IOException, it gives me an error that cannot have a catch in the same body as a try. This should probably be done in the action performed method.

GUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JPanel buttonPanel, topPanel, operationPanel;
JTextField display = new JTextField(20);

doMath math = new doMath();
String s = "";
String b= "";
//int counter;

JButton Num1;
JButton Num2;
JButton Num3;
JButton Num4;
JButton Num5;
JButton Num6;
JButton Num7;
JButton Num8;
JButton Num9;
JButton Num0;

JButton Add;
JButton Sub;
JButton Mult;
JButton Div;
JButton Eq;
JButton Clr;
JButton Space;
public GUI()
{
    super("Calculator");
    setSize(400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,1));

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();        
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
    buttonPanel.add(Num1 = new JButton("1"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num2 = new JButton("2"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num3 = new JButton("3"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num4 = new JButton("4"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num5 = new JButton("5"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num6 = new JButton("6"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num7 = new JButton("7"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num8 = new JButton("8"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num9 = new JButton("9"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num0 = new JButton("0"));        
    buttonPanel.add(Clr = new JButton("C"));
    buttonPanel.add(Eq = new JButton("="));
    buttonPanel.add(Add = new JButton("+"));
    buttonPanel.add(Sub = new JButton("-"));
    buttonPanel.add(Mult = new JButton("*"));
    buttonPanel.add(Div = new JButton("/"));
    buttonPanel.add(Space = new JButton("Space")); 

    Num1.addActionListener(this);
    Num2.addActionListener(this);
    Num3.addActionListener(this);
    Num4.addActionListener(this);
    Num5.addActionListener(this);
    Num6.addActionListener(this);
    Num7.addActionListener(this);
    Num8.addActionListener(this);
    Num9.addActionListener(this);
    Num0.addActionListener(this);
    Clr.addActionListener(this);
    Eq.addActionListener(this);
    Add.addActionListener(this);
    Sub.addActionListener(this);
    Mult.addActionListener(this);
    Div.addActionListener(this);
    Space.addActionListener(this);

    topPanel = new JPanel();         
    topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    topPanel.add(display);

    add(mainPanel);

    mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
    String text = source.getText();

try{
    if (text.equals("=")) 
    {
        doMath math = new doMath();

        b = b.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

        int result = math.doMath1(b);

        String answer = ""+result;
        display.setText(answer);

    }

    else if(text.equals("Space"))
    {        

            b+=" ";
            display.setText(b);

    }

    else if (text.equals("C"))
    {
        b = "";

        display.setText(b);
    }
    else if (text.equals("+") || text.equals("-") || text.equals("*") ||     text.equals("/"))
    {
         b += (" "+(text)+ " ");

        display.setText(b);
    }
    else 
    {

        b += (text);

        display.setText(b);

    }
    }
catch(IOException o)
{display.setText(b);} 

}
}
```

Comment: Please post the smallest complete snippet of code that causes the problem, and remove unnecessary whitespace so it's easier to read.

Comment: Why would you implement your own Stack class instead of using the one in the API

Comment: Your error is very strange. Could you please post exactly what syntax are you trying to use? Because try{...}catch(Exception e){...} should always work.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart OP is nesting the catch inside the try, based on his exception at the top, instead of completing the try then putting the exception block.

Comment: I do try{ the if statements in the actionperformed of my GUI class} then catch (IOException o) { display.setText(b);} and it still gives me that error

Answer (score 5):

> When I try using a try, catch IOException, it gives me an error that
>   cannot have a catch in the same body as a try

The error is self-explanatory.  The following code is illegal:

```
try{  
    catch(Exception ex){  
         }  
   }
```

You want this:

```
try{  
    //stuff i need to do  
   } //close the try  
  catch(IOException ioex)  
  {  
     //log and recover  
  }
```

**=UPDATE**

Based on the code block below (the same that OP is talking about in case it is changed later) The actual error message that is being displayed is this:

> Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never
>   thrown from the try statement body    GUI.java

The reason this occurs is that there is nothing that generates an `IOException` in your code, the only exception you can define without an explicit throw from one of your functions is the top level `Exception`.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JPanel buttonPanel, topPanel, operationPanel;
JTextField display = new JTextField(20);

doMath math = new doMath();
String s = "";
String b= "";
//int counter;

JButton Num1;
JButton Num2;
JButton Num3;
JButton Num4;
JButton Num5;
JButton Num6;
JButton Num7;
JButton Num8;
JButton Num9;
JButton Num0;

JButton Add;
JButton Sub;
JButton Mult;
JButton Div;
JButton Eq;
JButton Clr;
JButton Space;
public GUI()
{
    super("Calculator");
    setSize(400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,1));

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();        
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
    buttonPanel.add(Num1 = new JButton("1"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num2 = new JButton("2"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num3 = new JButton("3"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num4 = new JButton("4"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num5 = new JButton("5"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num6 = new JButton("6"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num7 = new JButton("7"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num8 = new JButton("8"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num9 = new JButton("9"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num0 = new JButton("0"));        
    buttonPanel.add(Clr = new JButton("C"));
    buttonPanel.add(Eq = new JButton("="));
    buttonPanel.add(Add = new JButton("+"));
    buttonPanel.add(Sub = new JButton("-"));
    buttonPanel.add(Mult = new JButton("*"));
    buttonPanel.add(Div = new JButton("/"));
    buttonPanel.add(Space = new JButton("Space")); 

    Num1.addActionListener(this);
    Num2.addActionListener(this);
    Num3.addActionListener(this);
    Num4.addActionListener(this);
    Num5.addActionListener(this);
    Num6.addActionListener(this);
    Num7.addActionListener(this);
    Num8.addActionListener(this);
    Num9.addActionListener(this);
    Num0.addActionListener(this);
    Clr.addActionListener(this);
    Eq.addActionListener(this);
    Add.addActionListener(this);
    Sub.addActionListener(this);
    Mult.addActionListener(this);
    Div.addActionListener(this);
    Space.addActionListener(this);

    topPanel = new JPanel();         
    topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    topPanel.add(display);

    add(mainPanel);

    mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
    String text = source.getText();

try{
    if (text.equals("=")) 
    {
        doMath math = new doMath();

        b = b.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

        int result = math.doMath1(b);

        String answer = ""+result;
        display.setText(answer);

    }

    else if(text.equals("Space"))
    {        

            b+=" ";
            display.setText(b);

    }

    else if (text.equals("C"))
    {
        b = "";

        display.setText(b);
    }
    else if (text.equals("+") || text.equals("-") || text.equals("*") ||     text.equals("/"))
    {
         b += (" "+(text)+ " ");

        display.setText(b);
    }
    else 
    {

        b += (text);

        display.setText(b);

    }
    }
catch(IOException o)
{display.setText(b);} 

}
}
```

Comment: I do try{ the if statements in the actionperformed of my GUI class} then catch (IOException o) { display.setText(b);} and it still gives me that error

Comment: @Big_Fan in the future post the block exactly as it is and further give us the correct error message.